# Javascript asynchronous for wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, electron

I'm trying to run an asynchronous for loop, which runs a synchronous function and then waits for a period of time. My code is :

```
function loopExec (i,imax, execFunc,param1) { 
    execFunc(i,param1);//Launch synchronous function which takes some time
    var y=i+1; 
    if (y < imax) {   //  if the counter < imax, call the loop function
        setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 0.1s setTimeout when the loop is called
            loopExec(y,imax, execFunc,param1);             //  ..  again which will trigger another call
        }, 100);
    }
    else if(y==imax){
        anotherFunction(param1);// The loop is over, clean up and log
    }
}
```

The behaviour that I want is :
execFunc(1) -> wait 100ms -> execFunc2-> wait...
[A bit like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evmVG.png)

The behaviour that I have is execFunc1, execFunc2, etc all launching at 100 ms interval, without waiting for completion of the previous one, resulting in a read/write conflict as these functions interact with files.

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I'm using electron/nodeJS.

Comment: exactly what you want to do. Please be clear

Comment: *"The behaviour that I have is execFunc1, execFunc2, etc all launching at 100 ms interval, without waiting for completion of the previous one"* The code above doesn't do that. It does what you said you want it to do. https://jsfiddle.net/23ta609b/

Comment: You may learn how to use promises.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : thanks for your link, but with the execFunc that I use, it does not work... I don't understand why.

Comment: @Aer0 : I started looking into promises but I'm still new to the concept

Comment: @Nygael: That would mean the function you're using it with isn't synchronous.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : It seems to be the answer, but I don't understant why, it should be a synchronous function.

Comment: @Nygael: You've tagged NodeJS; nearly all of Node's API functions are asynchronous unless you use the "sync" version of them (where "sync" versions exist).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: thing is, the code from execFunc is part of the code of a synchrnous function that I used in a normal "for" loop before. The only thing I changed is usage of global variables.

Comment: .@Nygael Do you need to wait exactly at least 100 ms or is it a guess to let the first function completes?

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder was right, the error is not in this function, but in the function it was calling.

This code does what is expected.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do something like this

[image]

this code will works.

```js
var i = 0;
var imax = 10;

function myFunction() {
  console.log('balbla', i);
  i+=1;
  if(i !== imax) setTimeout(myFunction, 100);
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 100);
```